# Printing a list into grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values that I want to display as grid:

> List = ["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbb","ccccccccc"]

I want them to print out like this

```
a a a a a a a a a

b b b b b b b b b

c c c c c c c c c
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a very simple problem, so it may help us help you if you explain what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: Actually I am having trouble with putting those characters into a 2D list and then printing out that 2D list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This two liners would be enough to solve your problem!

Try this:

```
>>> for values in List:
...     print (" ".join([chars for chars in values]), "\n")
```

And the output:

```
a a a a a a a a a

b b b b b b b b b

c c c c c c c c c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(line) for line in List));
```

Breakdown:

```
print(
    "\n".join(           #every line on its own line
        " ".join(line)   #add a space between each character
        for line in List #loop through List
    )
)
```

**Edit:** (Simpler solution)

```
print("\n".join(map(" ".join, List)))
```

Comment: You might need `"\n\n".join` at the top level, if a blank line is desired between the lines with actual content.

Answer (score 0):

One way (not the most efficient) will be to use 2 `for` loops, one to loop through each string in the list, and another to loop through each letter. And pass `" "` to the parameter `end` of the `print` function:

```
for string in List:
    for letter in string:
        print(letter, end = " ")
    print("\n")
```

**Output:**

```
a a a a a a a a a 

b b b b b b b b b 

c c c c c c c c c
```

Comment: I want there to be a space between them and print them more like a grid.

Comment: Can you also show me how I can create a 2d list from that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop and `" ".join()`. Then print a blank string for a newline (or you can use `'\n'`).

```
>>> List = ["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbb","ccccccccc"]
>>> for k in List:
...     print(" ".join(k))
...     print("")
... 
a a a a a a a a a

b b b b b b b b b

c c c c c c c c c

>>>
```

**Output with `'\n'` instead:

```
a a a a a a a a a


b b b b b b b b b


c c c c c c c c c
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
>>> li=["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbb","ccccccccc"]
>>> print(''.join(' '+c for s in li for c in s+'\n\n') )
 a a a a a a a a a 

 b b b b b b b b b 

 c c c c c c c c c
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more efficient: `print("\n\n".join((" ".join(list(line))) for line in List))`